# Updating the parameters of an existing trap and partially sending parameters in a trap

Tags: snmp, mib

We have created a list of traps (notifications) that our application is exposing and described it in a MIB file.

Today, we found ourselves in a situation where we need to update the MIB and add an additional (*optional*) parameter to the trap (update the Objects)
so that, in the end, we'll have an existing notification that has one more parameter.

My question is (because I really don't know what the SNMP manager will do):

1. If my customer *didn't* install the updated MIB with the updated objects in the trap, and I send the new parameter, what will happen on SNMP manager client side?
2. What will happen if the customer installed the new MIB and I send a trap *without* the new parameter?

Intuitively, as a developer, I would expect that everything will be OK, meaning that for (1) the trap will be seen (the new parameter showed without translation of OID, or not shown at all), and for (2) the trap will be seen and there will be no issues.

Also, in general, when a trap message definition has a parameter, is it mandatory or optional?

Answer (score 1):

The exact behavior depends on the manager.

In general, it's best to not change objects in a published MIB. You should create a new trap that contains the extra parameter. When you need to send without the extra param, use the old notification object. When you need to send the extra param, use the new object.